# how to query count by name DISTINCT in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

i have result of query before like this
[image: Result from first query]

and this is my first query

```
SELECT nama_parent, count(nama_parent)
  FROM `detail_order`
 WHERE received_date='2018-06-27'
 GROUP BY kode_resi
 ORDER BY `id_parent_cus` ASC
```

Actually the result final i wanted like this
[image: Final Result I Wanted]

How to query to get that results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results which you posted are correct I believe.
Because, you are grouping the records by `kode_resi` field.
If you include `kode_resi` into the select list you can realize the difference.
And you should use other non aggregate fields, being selected, into the `GROUP BY` clause also.

**Example**:

```
SELECT kode_resi, nama_parent, count( nama_parent ) AS `count`
  FROM `detail_order`
 WHERE received_date='2018-06-27'
 GROUP BY kode_resi, nama_parent
 ORDER BY kode_resi, nama_parent
```

For the expected result, you posted, you have to use grouping by `nama_parent`.
**Example**:

```
SELECT nama_parent, count( nama_parent ) AS `count`
  FROM `detail_order`
 WHERE received_date='2018-06-27'
 GROUP BY nama_parent
 ORDER BY nama_parent
```

Comment: thank you for your response Mr Ravinder.

But i still need the kode_resi on group by clause to filter all data record, and then i got the first result like image 1. I mean how to do single query to get result like image 2. thank you

Comment: It is hard to guess, but still ... on your results, try to apply `MAX` and `GROUP BY nama_parent`. But decide your self whether `MAX` is correct or not ...

Comment: hello Mr @Ravinder Reddy i have a new question about mysql. [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/211168/how-to-do-split-each-quantity-and-gruping-by-child-order-in-one-table-using-grou). hope you can help my problem, thank you :)